scipy.sparse.linalg.expm not returning self-consistent values
I am trying to compute a matrix exponential using scipy.sparse.linalg.expm but i realize it does not provide correct result when the numbers in the matrix are getting moderately high.
As a sanity check, i created a simple matrix
X = np.array([[06.1, 52.0],[016., 01.6 ]])

and then compute the product of exp(X)*exp(-X) to recover the identity matrix
Id = np.dot(expm(X),expm(-X))
I am expecting to get Id = ([[1, 0],[0, 1]]) but i get:
[[ 2.39599500e+08 -2.12377558e+08],[-6.89818242e+07  4.93089944e+08]]
Here is the full code:
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse.linalg import expm
X = np.array([[06.1, 52.0],
       [016., 01.6 ]])
Id = np.dot(expm(X),expm(-X))
print(Id)

To be noted that if I used smaller numbers in the matrix i will eventually get
Id = ([[1, 0],[0, 1]])
Another puzzling fact, a colleague of mine managed to get a consistent result when typing the exact same code as above on his python software.
Any thought? Thanks in advance

Thanks for the answer. In the case of 2-D arrays I believe a @ b is equivalent with numpy.dot(a, b). At least this is what I understand from the documentation. I tried with a@b and get the same result.

Have you tried a@b/(norm(a)*norm(b)). I think the only reason the terms in the product look huge is because the actual numbers in a and b are vast (about 1e14), so even a small relative error will be a large absolute error.

Note that numpy is numerical. So you cannot achieve what you want since expm is an approximation function. It does the calculation via iterations. Thus you cannot get results that cancel out

That 52 is giving problems.  15 looks better.  I haven't found any discussion as to whether pade approximation has problems with large numbers.

I think you triggered a known issue of scipy expm for 2x2 matrices, see https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/19584 and https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/20261. The fix is recent and probably not yet in the scipy version you are using. Also see the work in progess https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/20262
If you really need to compute expm of this matrix, one solution may be do normalize it by some integer and call np.linalg.matrix_power. Not sure this really improves numerical precision.
